# Hiding Edittext in spinner onItemSelected

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility, android-edittext, android-spinner

In one of my layouts I have a EditText that I show only when one spinner option is selected. In the rest of options is hide.

This action doesn't work, when I select one option the EditText is not hide or show, but if I select the same option again its work ok.

I manage the EditText visibility in spinner onItemSelected.

Any idea or solution?

I don't post my code because we have many leves of hierarchies in code and includes in layout.

Comment: "I don't post my code because we have many leves of hierarchies in code", Without your code how can we solve your issue?

Comment: yep, you should make a dummy, simple app, and if the issue persists in that as well, post that code

Comment: there is no way to help you if you didn't post any related code

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that's easy, you just have to move that thing to the other thing, it has to be after the third thing, okay?

Comment: LuckyMe I don't understand you.